Load React Modal with out refreshing parent component
I have been trying to understand how to populate my modal with asynchronous data and not cause the parent page to rerender. I have tried making a separate context for the modal, moving modal out of parent component but with this I still need to click the modal open from inside the parent.
Card Component
import React, { useContext, useState, useRef, memo } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { ShowProvider } from "../../ModalContext";
import { ShowContext } from "../../ModalContext";
import uniqid from "uniqid";
import { getText } from "../../helpers/getData";
import Modal from "../Modal/Modal";
import "./Card.css";

const customStyles = {
  content: {
    width: "70vw",
    height: "60vh",
    top: "50%",
    left: "50%",
    right: "auto",
    bottom: "auto",
    marginRight: "-50%",
    transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
  },
};

const Card = (props) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { showData, setShowData } = useContext(ShowContext);

  const img = props.book.book_image;
  const title = props.book.title;

  // get id then call for individual description
  const getSummary = async (title) => {
    const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${title}&key=${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_KEY}`;
    const response = await getText(url);
    const description = response.data.items[0].volumeInfo.description;
    console.log(description);
    setShowData({ description: description });
    console.log(showData);
  };

  const open = () => {
    console.log("open");
    setShowData({ show: true });
    getSummary(title);
  };

  const closed = () => {
    console.log("close");
    setShowData({ ...showData, show: false });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <main>
        <Modal show={showData.show} handleClose={closed}>
          <p> {showData.description}</p>
        </Modal>

        <button type="button" className="open" onClick={open}>
          Description
        </button>

        <li className="card">
          <img src={img} alt="book cover" key={uniqid()}></img>
        </li>
      </main>
    </>
  );
};

export default Card;

PARENT COMPONENT
import React, { useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { Context } from "../../../Context";
import "./Best.css";
import { getData } from "../../../helpers/getData";
import Card from "../.././Card/Card";
import Results from "../.././Results/Results";
import AnimatedLayout from "../../AnimatedLayout";

const Best = () => {
  const { data, setData } = useContext(Context);

  const getCurrent = async () => {
    const url = `https://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v3/lists/hardcover-fiction.json?api-key=XYZ&pages=1`;
    const response = await getData(url);
    if (response.message) {
      console.log(response.message);
      setData({ ...data, error: response.message });
      alert(response.message);
    }
    console.log(response);
    const newArr = data.results.slice();
    const newData = [...newArr, ...response];
    setData({ ...data, results: [...newData] });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setData({ ...data, results: [] });
    getCurrent();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Results>
      <AnimatedLayout>
        <ul className="results-ul horizontal">
          <li className="error fade">{data.error}</li>
          {data.results.map((book) => {
            return <Card book={book}>CARD</Card>;
          })}
        </ul>
      </AnimatedLayout>
    </Results>
  );
};

export default Best;


What exactly do you mean by "load modal with data"? The parent Best component fetches data and updates state, which will obviously trigger a component rerender. The modal opening logic appears to be in the child Card component. Are you saying that when the Card components toggle the modals that the Best component rerenders? Is this causing any actual problem? Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with here? The contexts and where/how they are rendered and where/how these parent/child components are rendered?

Yes, when modal component inside card component toggles it renders page not only card.  The parent data fetch gets called in the process. I will work on a minimal example to make it more clear.  Thank you.

The Best component only calls the useEffect once since it has an empty dependency array, so it should only fetch data once after the initial mounting. Is Best being conditionally rendered by something higher that it in the ReactTree? Yes, a more complete code example would help show this.

After some more tinkering I realized that my toggle logic was off.  I changed the placement of some of my setShow variables and it worked. Thankyou for your help Drew an Joe

I think you just need to memoize the Best component: export default React.memo(Best)
From React's docs

memo
memo lets you skip re-rendering a component when its props are unchanged.

https://react.dev/reference/react/memo

The Best component is defined const Best = () => { ... }, so there are no props to memoize on.
